# Engine rear nozzle outside vs inside

Tags: engine

I'm not sure if it's called nozzle or something else. I'm talking about the cone shaped part of GA engines at the rear.

Older engines, for example this Trent 700 had the cowling covering whole of the turbine -

[image]

Ow newer engines, the rear part of turbine is exposed -

[image]

What difference does this have on the engine performance? Is this to accommodate the increasing bypass ratio of modern engines?